# How can I calculate $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-k+1} i{n-i \choose k-1} / {n \choose k}$ for known $n$ and $k$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

How can I calculate $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-k+1} \dfrac{i{n-i \choose k-1}} {n \choose k}$$ for specific $n$ and $k?$

Comment: Avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication. That's a common practice in programming, not in Mathematics, where it has other meaning. Use (ideally) juxtaposition, \cdot ($\cdot$) or \times ($\times$)

Comment: What have you tried? Is there a reason you expect a closed formula? Have you tried specific values of $n,k?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove
$$\sum_i \binom{i}{1}\binom{1}{1}\binom{n-i}{k-1} = \binom{n+1}{k+1}$$
combinatorially by counting $(k+1)$-subsets of $\{1,\dots,n+1\}$ according to the second smallest element $i+1$.
Then
$$\sum_i \frac{i\binom{n-i}{k-1}}{\binom{n}{k}} = \frac{\sum_i i\binom{n-i}{k-1}}{\binom{n}{k}} = \frac{\binom{n+1}{k+1}}{\binom{n}{k}} = \frac{\frac{n+1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}}{\binom{n}{k}} = \frac{n+1}{k+1}.$$